# Clicking 'back' on a form unloads web resource

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Say I have a form with a web resource on it, when viewing the form and clicking the web browser's 'back' button the web resource seems to unload, if I click the back button again then it behaves as I'd expect.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a way to prevent the web resource from unloading when a user clicks 'back'?

**Note**: This seems to happen in both IE (10,11) and Chrome, but not Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue, looks like a bug.
Until Microsoft fixes it, use the following in your webresource to trap the back event and redirect it properly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    $(window).on('popstate', function () {
        var hashLocation = location.hash;
        var hashSplit = hashLocation.split("#!/");
        var hashName = hashSplit[1];
        if (hashName !== '') {
            var hash = window.location.hash;
            window.parent.history.back();
            window.parent.history.back();
        }
    });
    window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');
}
```

}